# What types of tech reports are there in Bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I use the `@techreport` entry for documents such as ISO standards. For instance:

```
@techreport{ISO-19156,
  type = {Standard},
  key = {ISO 19156:2011},
  year = {2011},
  title = {{Geographic information -- Observations and measurements}},
  volume = {2011},
  address = {Geneva, CH},
  institution = {International Organization for Standardization}
}
```

The keyword `type` seems to be setting the kind of output. Beyond `Standard` what other types of technical reports can be declared with this entry?

Comment: It depends on the bibtex style which entry types and fields it supports.

Comment: I use `apalike`, or the specific style of the Journal I submit to. Is this information available anywhere?